# C# Opposite of "Anonymous" Function

Tags: c#, generic-programming

When I try to say:

- I moved an anonymous method to a **?** one

where **?** is meant to describe just a normal function, with a name, return type, named arguments etc.

What would be the correct adjective to use, *eg*. Concrete, Named, Normal, Class, Member, Identified ... ?

Comment: I'd say named: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869312/c-anonymous-method-vs-named-method

Comment: Anonymous methods are also called as unnamed methods so apposite is named method.

Comment: What do you mean, something like `.Select(int.Parse)` vs. `.Select(str => int.Parse(str))`?

Comment: According to Microsoft it's a [`named method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98dc08ac.aspx)